# Populating a Dropdown with all instances of a text box in Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this. I'm creating a PDF form in Adobe LiveCycle and I’m trying to populate a drop-down box with all instances of a text field called _KeyPeople.txtInitials.  This field could have up to 10 instances. I've been bouncing around Adobe website and forms for quite some time now and no luck.

Please tell me if I’m mistaken, but my thought is every time they change an instance of this text field it will clear this dropdown and repopulate the list box please.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: I know that you can use data binding but I have never done such, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript. On change or exit event of you text field you can 
add something like:

```
DropDownList1.clearItems();
DropDownList1.addItem(TextField1.rawValue);
DropDownList1.rawValue = TextField1.rawValue;
```

For more Adobe LiveCycle JavaScript samples see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/DesignerScriptingRef/WS92d06802c76abadb-3e14850712a151d270d-7ffa.html#WS92d06802c76abadb-3e14850712a151d270d-74ca)